# Не могу сменить пароль администратора в nextcloud

Tags: nextcloud

Долгое время пользовался Nextcloud и в какой-то момент слетел пароль администратора.
После чего не могу восстановить ..

При попытке сменить по рекомендации из официального источника, выдает ошибку:
Error 97 of the php line when executing the command
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /var/www/www-root/data/www/***domain***/php/nextcloud/console.php on line 94

Сталкивался ли кто-либо с подобным ? Спасибо!